# Special redirect by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a menu in Flash without access to it's links. One of the items leads to this link: `http://dev.infinityfitness.pl/rozklad`, but the domain is not mine.

Is it possible to override this link using htaccess that if user clicks in this menu item the redirect leads him to something like this `http://infinityfit.dnawrot.nazwa.pl/rozklad`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .htaccess file would need to reside on the domain you don't have access to, unfortunately.

Comment: I know, after a while I understood that when the page is loaded the link I follow is already in browser, that means my local computer, so there's no way to interact with htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to "intercept" client side links inside of a flash app if you don't have access to the source code.